# не работает print

Tags: python, print

начал решать задачу, и решил протестировать простую конструкцию, но почему-то print не заработал

```
mat=[]
dobavka=True
while dobavka:
  stroka=input().split()
  if stroka=='end': 
    break
  else:
    mat.append(stroka)
print(mat)
```

Comment: split() создаёт список, который вы потом сравниваете со строкой. Но список никогда в жизни не будет равне строке, поэтому цикл не прерывается тоже никогда в жизни

Comment: благодарю за разъяснение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что Ваш цикл никогда не останавливается.

```
mat = []
dobavka = True
while dobavka:
    stroki = input().split()
    for stroka in stroki:
        if stroka == 'end':
            dobavka = False 
            break
        else:
            mat.append(stroka)
print(mat)
```